# error: type List does not take parameters

Tags: java, list, compiler-errors, generic-type-argument

I get the following error despite it's exactly one used in examples:

> error: type List does not take parameters

```
List<String> strings_wat = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Java is version 1.7 and the class is NOT named `ArrayList`.

Comment: You're importing the wrong `List`. It's supposed to be `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You are likely importing `java.awt.List`.

You should instead import `java.util.List`, which is a parameterized type.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But what is the difference and how a newcomer to Java is supposed to know one?

Comment: @ror6ax The `awt` package is for building GUIs, so `java.awt.List` is a GUI object. `java.util.List` is not.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you are importing it from `java.awt`:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

and it looks like you want to use the one from `java.util`:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are working on Graphical user interface you have to
`import java.awt.List` instead of `import java.util.List`
Other then else if you are working on simple code you have to `import java.util.List;`  instead of `import java.awt.List`

Answer (score 1):

[image: I Was Getting Same Error !]

See I was also facing this problem, now i will tell you how i solved that problem .
Firstly i was totally confused and not getting any solution then i copied that code and pasted into another directory and there code was running. Then i found a file name which was Deque.java and because of this i was getting this error. Reason that Deque.java class was public class and when i want to use Deque class of java..util.*; package then compiler searches for a file with a matching name and .java extension. If such a file exists, it could potentially cause conflicts, especially if you have a class with the same name.

Then I deleted that file or you can rename that file. After this you will not get this error.
In my case i was getting error because of this Deque file in your case it can be ArrayList or LinkedList , please check the file names in that directory it can solve your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am getting solved this problem by renaming the class name or file name as in Notepad++.

You Should not take the class names as **ArrayList or List.**
And you also need to add the following package

> import java.util.*;

My Previous class name is **List** I changed it into the Names.so You have to change the class name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).