# How to add text at second last line in text file using java

Tags: java

I have a text file in which there are multiple lines. I need to edit this text file dynamically. But I want to add dynamic text at second last line of the text file.

```
class FileAppending 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try{

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                  new FileOutputStream("file path\\x.txt", true), "UTF-8");
            int lines = 0;
            while (br.readLine != 0){
                lines++; // by this i'll get exact line number
            }
            BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            fbw.write("append txt...");
            fbw.newLine();
            fbw.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Now i need some thing which will help me to add text at second last line since i have total number of lines

Answer (score 7):

You can do it this way

```
    List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path"));
    list.add(list.size() - 1, "text");
    Files.write(Paths.get("path"), list);
```

Comment: i'm getting an error as 'type List does not take parameters' at this line 'List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path"));'. can you plz advise...!!!

Comment: are you importing java.awt.List instead of java.util.List?    see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955621/list-does-not-take-parameters

Comment: @Rakesh it's valid for 1.7+

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply guyz...now i'm getting error at 'List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path"));' and reason as 'actual and formal argument lists differ in length'. It is prompting me to enter characterSet to enter (by default it is coming as null)
like = 'List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path"),null);'

Comment: @RakeshPrajapati 
 
the call with just the path parameter is there since 1.8 (what java version do you use?). if < 1.8 use: Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) ... it's the same as if you call with just one parameter